# Почему — везет?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Когда человеку улыбается удача, говорят, что ему "везет". Интересно, почему именно везет? Кого, куда и на чем везет?

Comment: Интересное совпадение: в японском 運 (ун) значит "удача", 運ぶ (хакобу) значит "нести/везти".

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, в самом первом исконном значении"перемещать кого-либо или что-либо с помощью каких-либо транспортных средств ", а в переносном значении - с помощью каких-либо сил.То есть когда приходит везение, то  включается какая-то сила извне, которая везёт человека к его цели, к чему-то желаемому.

Comment: Тогда было бы "везёт его", а не "везёт ему".

Comment: Но ведь теперь везёт - категория состояния в безличном предложении, а все безличные связаны с представлениями предков о том, что это делает ОНО - что-то сверхъестественное, божество например.

Comment: Мы же говорим о происхождении слова

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, что "везти" - потому, что когда тебя везут к цели, это лучше, чем когда сам идешь.
Не совсем понятно, правда, (в варианте Людмилы тоже) - почему не ему/тебе, а не его/тебя... Но такие вещи встречаются: "ему идет" - из того же ряда.

Comment: Ему идет костюм, а ему везет - что?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю "повезло" связано со словом "вязание".

В славянской мифологии была такая довольно почитаемая богиня Мокошь (Макошь). Она точно связана с прядением и ткачеством, и возможно (по ак. Б. А. Рыбакову) является ещё богиней судьбы. Пряха судьбы - довольно частотный мифологический образ в Европе, можно вспомнить ещё греческих мойр и скандинавских норн, так что наличие подобного образа и у славян очень вероятно, к тому же для исключительно женского божества она очень высоко расположена в пантеоне. В этом случае вполне могло образоваться, что-то вроде,- "ему (судьбу)вяжет (богиня)". В дальнейшем вязание и везение уже разошлись, связь с богиней судьбы подзабылась, а вот слово осталось. Косвенно эту версию подтверждает попадавшаяся мне православная апологетика, где противопоставлялись божья **благодать** и **везение** от бесов.

Хотя не исключаю, что на окончательно словообразование повлиял глагол "везти" (чего-либо). Если ветер попутный или возу по дороге, то отдыхаешь - *повезло тебя*, а не повезло, так вёслами грести или пешком топать надо. Путь из варяг в греки затрагивал многие районы Руси и подобное выражение вполне могло появится у моряков или бродяг и путешественников.

Comment: Мне нравится мысль о Макоши. Это Богиня Судьбы,Воплощение Матери Сырой Земли, изображаемая с коровьей головой, потом коровья голова преобразилась в Рог Изобилия, так что вполне похоже на то, что "везучего" везёт к изобилию сама Макошь. Это и есть та неведомая сила, о которой я сказала в ответе.

Comment: @Людмила, при "везёт" на чём-то куда-то, Мокошь как-то не очень смотрится. Напрягать для возки женщину, пусть и богиню не по-мужски как-то. Скорей уж тогда бесы на телеге в ад везут. А богиня ве**С**ти может, а ве**З**ти - нет.

 Поэтому и связь с изменившимся "вязанием" мне и кажется логичнее, чем с перевозкам.